# How to use and operator and or operator together in CLIPS programming

Tags: clips

I want to add a **else** part for below code as **(assert (diabetes-assume false))**. I glad if someone can help me to fix this issue.

```
(defrule diabetes-adult
     (disease ?d)
     (body-status ?b)
     (age ?a&:(and (eq ?d none) (>= ?a 19) (< ?a 51) (or (eq ?b obesity) (eq ?b overweight) )))
     =>
     (assert (diabetes-assume true)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assume as part of your initial state that diabetes is false and then define a higher salience rule (than the rules which rely on that assumption) to change the assumption to true:

```
(deffacts assumptions
   (diabetes-assume false))
   
(defrule diabetes-adult-true
     (declare (salience 10))
     ?f <- (diabetes-assume false)
     (disease ?d)
     (body-status ?b)
     (age ?a&:(and (eq ?d none) 
                   (>= ?a 19) 
                   (< ?a 51) 
                   (or (eq ?b obesity) (eq ?b overweight))))
     =>
     (retract ?f)
     (assert (diabetes-assume true)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.